# Inclusion of the quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> Given a group $G$ and its normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$, s.t. $N_1\subset N_2$. Prove that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G/N_1$, such that $ H \simeq G/N_2$.

---

There is a one Claiming the above statement is right.

In my thought, this statement looks like a false.

But Can't find Any counterexample of the above statement.

Then, Is that true statement?

Comment: Thank you for fixing, @Bach :)

Comment: No. That's not condition of the problem. If the statement  is true, Goal of the proof is existence of the $H$ which is normal or subgroup. Given condition is just group $G$, its normal $N_1$ and $N_2$

Comment: No problem. That's o.k. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint: $N_1$ is a red herring. If $(G,N_1,N_2)$ is a counterexample, then so is $(G/N_1,1,N_2/N_1)$, so you may take $N_1=1$.

Using the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, you can prove the statement is true for abelian groups, so a good start is to look at small non-abelian groups.

The smallest counterexample (I think) has $|G|=8$, $N_1=1$, $|N_2|=2$

Comment: There's a group of order 8 with a quotient isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$ but for which all subgroups of order 4 are cyclic

Comment: I see... you mean the quaternion group $Q_8$.